# Движение шагового двигателя Arduino

Tags: arduino

Сделал градусник с вертикальной шкалой , подключил датчик , при считывании температуры раз в N минут двигатель вращает направляющую, стрелка едет к температуре на N сигналов. При увеличении температуры - стрелка штатно едет вверх, при уменьшении - почему то так же вверх, хотя должна вниз .Все данные в порт выводятся верные ( температура, в какую поз по сигналам нужно ехать и т.д.) Помогите разобраться. Вот часть кода с движением :

```
void moveStepperToPosition(int position) {
  long targetPosition1 = position * stepsPerDegree;
  Serial.print("dvijenie v poz: ");
  Serial.println(targetPosition1);

  if (stepper.currentPosition() < targetPosition1) {
    Serial.println("dvigaemsya vverx...");
      stepper.moveTo(targetPosition1);   
      stepper.runToPosition();  
  } else if (stepper.currentPosition() > targetPosition1) {
    Serial.println("dvigaemsya vniz...");
     stepper.moveTo(targetPosition1);  
     stepper.runToPosition();
  }

 else {
  Serial.println("yje tyt .");
}

while (stepper.distanceToGo() != 0) {
  stepper.run();
  delay(1);
```

---

position - градусы с датчика
stepsPerDegree - количество шагов двигателя на 1 градус ( задаю сам в зависимости от размеров шкалы градусника)

Comment: Какой тип двигателя, какой драйвер, как подключено?

Comment: Вероятно, следует вызывать `runToNewPosition` вместо `moveTo`, см. [Moving a stepper motor to two places with one command and AccelStepper library](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/moving-a-stepper-motor-to-two-places-with-one-command-and-accelstepper-library/1034509)

Comment: step/dir подключения плюс драйвер их же фирмы  , двигатель шаговый PL42H48-D5
Когда тестовый код запускаю ,указываю текущую позицию условно 1000, а движение  в поз. 500, то едет вниз на 500 сигналов исправно ,в моем же коде в любом раскладе едет вверх.

Comment: runToNewPosition не работает ,пытался уже и скорость для движения вниз задавать отдельно -300 ,ничего не срабатывает ,все равно вверх двигается

Comment: В каком диапазоне меняются значения у Вас в `targetPosition1` и в таком же аргументе в примере, где все работает? Может в драйверах просто стоит операция по модулю и Ваши значения обрезают? И вообще, было бы хорошо, если бы Вы в вопросе привели и код работающего примера (или хотя бы ссылку на него).

Comment: И еще, если команда `stepper.moveTo();` производит абсолютное позиционирование, то какой смысл в Вашем условном операторе с одинаковыми ветвями? - только ради вывода в терминал "вверх"/"вниз"? А остальные команды?

Comment: @Vladimir , диапазон 50 сигналов ,что равно 1 градусу ,что равно StepePerDegree, если перепад более 1 градуса ,то разницу на 50 умножаем. Условные 24 градуса = позиции 1200 сигналов ,если понижается до 23 ,то в позицию 1150 должен ехать, но двигается не в том направлении

Comment: @Vladimir 

void setup() {
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(200.0);
  stepper.setAcceleration(100.0);
  stepper.setCurrentPosition(1000);
}
void loop() {
  stepper.moveTo(500); 
  stepper.runToPosition(); 
}
 тут работает исправно ,вывод куда едет (вверх или вниз) тоже хотелось бы оставить .